# Magento 2.1 : How can I save a shipping address using the REST V1 API

Tags: magento2, checkout, api, magento-2.1, rest-api

I'm trying to save just the shipping address using the REST V1 API of Magento 2. I know there is [an endpoint to save the billing-address](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#!/quoteBillingAddressManagementV1), but there seems to be lack of a way to save the shipping address.

There is a [shipping-information endpoint](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#!/checkoutGuestShippingInformationManagementV1), but this requires you to already set your shipping method.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? In Magento 2.2 I can use billing-address endpoint to set the Billing and Shipping address to the same thing, but can't work out how to set a different shipping address without affecting the billing address.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I guess that there is no endpoint to save shipping address in Magento 2.x

But I am using this for saving shipping address:
**PUT** `/V1/customers/me/` with 2 fields below in body json:

```
"default_shipping": true,
"default_billing": true
```